# datatable return all data if not selected anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

**Following is the JQuery code**

```
initComplete: function() {
    var i = 1;
    this.api().columns([1, 2, 3, 4]).every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple="multiple"><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo($("#filter" + i))
            .on('change', function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (val !== null) {
                    var selectd_value = '';
                    for (var j = 0; j <= parseFloat(val.length) - 1; j++) {
                        var value = val[j].replace(/[^a-z A-Z 0-9]/g, "");
                        value = value.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
                        if (j != parseFloat(val.length) - 1) {
                            selectd_value += value + '|';
                        } else {
                            selectd_value += value;
                        }
                    }
                    column.search(selectd_value, true, false).draw();
                } else {
                    this.rows().data().draw();
                }
            });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });
        i++;
    });
}
```

Anyone can please help me why else block is not working? How can I draw the table with all data if nothing is selected?

Comment: try your if with  if (val !== null & val !== undefined && val != '')

Comment: Bro it executing else condition but with an error.